# 301 redirect works on Local Machine but not on Live server (Asp.Net)

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect

I need to do 301 redirect for some pages and I added the code in the global.asax in the application_beginRequest(). It works fine on my local machine. When I update the site's dll on the live server, it doesnt work. Any ideas? Could it be the IIS server configuration?

I am using VS2012 and Asp.Net Webforms 3.5 Framework locally.

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

        if (path.EndsWith(".xml") || !path.Contains("."))
        {
            RedirectOldPages(path);
        }
    }

    private void RedirectOldPages(string path)
    {

        //PagesToBeRedirected is a static class with a dictionary in it
        if (PagesToBeRedirected.RedirectPages.ContainsKey(path))
        {
            //301 Permanent Redirect Page
            Response.Redirect(PagesToBeRedirected.RedirectPages[path], false);
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently;
            CompleteRequest();
        }

     }
```

Comment: Can you share the code for further analysis?

Comment: Define: "doesn't work". What HTTP response is being sent to the client?

Comment: I am getting a 404 file not found. Which is true, that's why I am doing the redirect.